# Quaternion from Euler angles and Quaternion Vector multiplication glitching out

Tags: c++, math, vector, quaternions

I've been working on a project for some time and Needed something that could from a Vector3 representing rotation in the XYZ axis make Forward, Right and Up vectors. I was looking through a lot of stuff and after some time I figured out I had to implement Quaternions (I have my own Math Libary but this same thing happened with glm) and Here is the code for calculating the Forward Vector: (quaternion is the rotation Quaternion member in my class and Quaternion::Euler is a static function that returns a Quaternion from Euler Angles)

```
quaternion = Quaternion::Euler(rotation);
Vector3 ret = quaternion * Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

when the rotation is `0, 0, 0` the function returns `0, 0, 1` as it should, but if I try something like `0, 180, 0` it should return `0, 0, -1`, but instead I get `-8.74228e-08, 0, -1`. After some investigation I figured out that the Quaternion::Euler function returns a Quaternion where the `w` part is messed up. In the case where the rotation is `0, 180, 0` the Quaternion the Quaternion::Euler function returns is `0, 1, 0, -4.37113883e-08` which is almost exactly half of the random number the Forward functions returns. Here is Quaternion::Euler:

```
float x = Radians(euler.x);
float y = Radians(euler.y);
float z = Radians(euler.z);

x = x / 2;
y = y / 2;
z = z / 2;

return Quaternion(cos(z) * cos(y) * sin(x) - sin(z) * sin(y) * cos(x), //X
                  cos(z) * sin(y) * cos(x) + sin(z) * cos(y) * sin(x), //Y
                  sin(z) * cos(y) * cos(x) - cos(z) * sin(y) * sin(x), //Z
                  cos(z) * cos(y) * cos(x) + sin(z) * sin(y) * sin(x));//W
```

and Honestly, I stole this function from an article of a guy that was making his own Math Engine, in his case this seemed to work. Here is the Quaternion Vector Multiplication function, that I "borrowed" from the Unity Implementation: (in this case it's inside the Quaternion struct so `this` is a pointer to the quaternion from the Quaternion Vector multiplication)

```
inline Vector3 operator*(const Vector3& other) {

    float x = this->x * 2.0f;
    float y = this->y * 2.0f;
    float z = this->z * 2.0f;
    float xx = this->x * x;
    float yy = this->y * y;
    float zz = this->z * z;
    float xy = this->x * y;
    float xz = this->x * z;
    float yz = this->y * z;
    float wx = this->w * x;
    float wy = this->w * y;
    float wz = this->w * z;

    Vector3 ret;

    ret.x = (1.0f - (yy + zz)) * other.x + (xy - wz) * other.y + (xz + wy) * other.z;
    ret.y = (xy + wz) * other.x + (1.0f - (xx + zz)) * other.y + (yz - wx) * other.z;
    ret.z = (xz - wy) * other.x + (yz + wx) * other.y + (1.0f - (xx + yy)) * other.z;

    return ret;

}
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong ? I tried to do this with glm:

```
glm::quat quat(glm::vec3(glm::radians(rotation.x), glm::radians(rotation.y), glm::radians(rotation.z)));
glm::vec3 v = quat * glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

but it's the same thing, the vector is the same and the quaternion is the same too, I've been reading into things a lot about this and couldn't find a fix, always when I tried to search implementation for the Quaternio::Euler function it just came up with how to use a math library. It would be best if the solution wouldn't require me to use glm, because I have to use my own Math Library, but honestly I will try anything to at least understand what is wrong.

Comment: While I read "... ```0, 0, -1```, but instead I get ```-8.74228e-08, 0, -1``` ..." there is one thing I see.  ```-8.74228e-08``` is the same thing as  ```-0.0000000874228``` , so is -8.74 divided by 10^8. Yeah, not exactly 0, but almost. Sometimes it is just impossible to get exactly zero when performing float or double 3D transformations. If it is a normal or a rotation, it is indistinguishable by 0. Just one more small thing. Be attentive how you use in further calculations. Sometimes these approximations if are systematic, accumulates and results in big errors.

Comment: I figured that out and my solution was to just set it to zero if it was too close to zero, but that would only work if the rotation in any axis was a multiple of 90 degrees. so if it was something like 45 degrees and the output should be something like "0.5, 0, 0.5" instead it is something like "0.745484, 0, 0.745484"